# GridView with CheckBox, CheckedChanged always true the first time

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a pretty standard GridView. This includes a TemplateField with a checkbox. I set the checkboxes to checked/unchecked based on values in a database.
The checkboxes have a CheckedChanged event. After the page has loaded the first time I click a checkbox that is checked. The CheckedChanged event fires, but the CheckBox always has `Checked = true`. Any subsequent clicks on checkboxes, and the information in the event is correct.

What is causing this?

### .aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="MyGV" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCreated="MyGV_RowCreated" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My checkboxes">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="MyCheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        MyGV.DataSource = myfetcheddata;
        MyGV.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void MyGV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
    if (isSomethingMarkedInDatabase) {
        MyCheckBox.Checked = true;
    }
}

protected void MyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (MyCheckBox.Checked) {
        // This is always run the first time a checkbox is clicked, whether or not it was checked or not in the first place. Any subsequent clicks on checkboxes has correct behaviour here.
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `RowCreated` instead of `RowDataBound`?   `RowCreated` is always triggered, so on each and every postback, before the events are triggered. So maybe it is fixed if you move that code to `RowDataBound` which is only called after `grid.DataBind()`.

```
protected void MyGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        CheckBox MyCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
        MyCheckBox.Checked = isSomethingMarkedInDatabase;
    }
}
```

You can access the datasource in `RowDataBound`. If you want to evaluate a field in the record you have to cast `e.Row.DataItem` to the actual type(f.e. a `DataRowView`).

Comment: I updated the comment in `CheckedChanged` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I changed to `RowDataBound` instead of `RowCreated`, and now it works as it should. Any idea why `RowCreated` introduced this strange behaviour? I had used debugging to see if `RowCreated` was called again to overwrite the value, but `RowCreated` was only called once (when the GridView was rendered, then never again).

Comment: @GTHvidsten: because `RowCreated` must be called on every postback as first step to create all controls. All things that are persisted in viewstate and that depend on the datasource belong into `RowDataBound`. When the `Checked` state is changed in RowCreated at `MyCheckBox.Checked = isSomethingMarkedInDatabase;`, then this happens before the `CheckedChanged`-event was triggered. That causes your issue. `RowDataBound` fixes this issue because it is not triggered on postback (unless you don't call `DataBind`).

Comment: How is `MyCheckBox.Checked = isSomethingMarkedInDatabase` called? I tried setting a breakpoint there when debugging, and that line was not called when I checked/unchecked a checkbox, only one time when the page was first loaded.